# Why don't I see the request variable I set in the first script?

Tags: php, request, superglobals

As I try to retrieve the variable `status` from the `$_REQUEST[]` array I set in the first script (and then do a redirect), I see nothing but a warning `Undefined index: status`. Why is that ?

```
<?php
        $_REQUEST['status'] = "success";
        $rd_header = "location: action_script.php";
        header($rd_header);
?>
```

---

*action script.php*

```
<?php
echo "Unpacking the request variable : {$_REQUEST['status']}";
```

Comment: Because in your header statement you are not passing any parameters... It's a fresh URL with a clean `$_REQUEST` variable.

Comment: If you put a banknote into one pocket, does it surprise you if you cannot find it in another?

Comment: @Lix how to send a parameter with the header function ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php I don't see it in the doc

Comment: @YourCommonSense yeah it will ! I often forget which pocket I put the banknote into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your `header()` statement redirects the user to a brand new URL. Any `$_GET` or `$_POST` parameters are no longer there because we are no longer on the same page.

You have a few options.

1- Firstly you can use `$_SESSION` to persist data across page redirection.

```
session_start();
$_SESSIONJ['data'] = $data; 
// this variable is now held in the session and can be accessed as long as there is a valid session.
```

2- Append some get parameters to your URL when redirecting -

```
$rd_header = "location: action_script.php?param1=foo&param2=bar";
header($rd_header);
// now you'll have the parameter `param1` and `param2` once the user has been redirected.
```

For the second method, [this documentation might be usefull](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). It is a method to create a query string from an array called `http_build_query()`.

Comment: Don't forget to use the correct encoding with `http_build_query`: for GET, this is RFC 3986.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['status'] = "success";
    $rd_header = "location: action_script.php";
    header($rd_header);
?>

<?php
    session_start();
    echo "Unpacking the request variable : {$_SESSION['status']}";
```

Note the addition of `session_start()` at the top of both pages. As you'll read in the link I posted this is required and must be on all pages you wish to use sessions.

Comment: no not a session..But sending the parameter as a request variable

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is probably sending a GET parameter:

```
$rd_header = "Location: action_script.php?status=success";
header($rd_header);
```

that can be retrieved in the `action_script.php` via:

```
$_GET['status'];
```

You don't really need sessions or cookies in this case but you have to consider the fact that a GET post can be easily edited by the user.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the problem of "trusting" the data in a `$_GET` request. **Never trust those users!** ;)